# Google Maps API not working in onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps API. On loading the page it is working fine, but for my requirement when `onclick` the button, I want to show the Google Map. My working code:

```js
function initMap() {
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: {
      lat: 12.9577129,
      lng: 77.6764937
    } // Starting Point Marathahalli
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;

  /* configure waypoints */
  var waypts = [];
  waypts.push({
    location: {
      lat: 12.9583665,
      lng: 77.6635659
    }, // HAL
    stopover: true
  }, {
    location: {
      lat: 12.9630167,
      lng: 77.6268656
    },
    stopover: true
  });

  directionsService.route({
    origin: {
      lat: 12.9577129,
      lng: 77.6764937
    }, // Haight.
    destination: {
      lat: 12.9868068,
      lng: 77.6070679
    }, // Ending Point Shivaji Nagar.
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
    waypoints: waypts
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      console.log(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Travel modes in directions</title>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7lDrYPDmJz1JsQh2rbWA9uRZHcFk_xJY&callback=initMap">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="testForm">

    <select name="tripId">
  <option value="">Select trip</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>

    <button type="button" id="btn-submit">submit</button>
  </form><br></br>

  <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
    <select id="mode">
      <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The code that I tried with `onclick` event:

```
$('#btn-submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url :"getLatLan.php",
         data : $('#testForm').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(res);
           },
         error:function(exception){
         alert('Exeption:'+exception);
        }
        });

});
```

I *am* getting a response in AJAX (`console.log(res);`):

```
{
"status": "success",
"count": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "tripId": "1",
        "pickUpLatitidute": "",
        "pickUpLongitude": "",
        "cabNo": "Ad2K2001",
        "driverId": "G2E100",
        "routeId": "1",
        "tripDate": "2017-08-01 15:45:55",
        "startTime": "15:45:55",
        "endTime": "14:48:55",
        "shiftId": "1",
        "tripStatus": "0",
        "id": "1",
        "empId": "G2E201",
        "callStartTime": "",
        "callEndTime": "",
        "cabReachingTime": "",
        "pickupTime": "15:50:02",
        "dropTime": "",
        "dropStatus": "0",
        "otp": "421283",
        "pickupotpStatus": "1",
        "empPresentStatus": "0",
        "latitdute": "12.9583665",
        "longitude": "77.6635659"
    },
    {
        "tripId": "1",
        "pickUpLatitidute": "",
        "pickUpLongitude": "",
        "cabNo": "Ad2K2001",
        "driverId": "G2E100",
        "routeId": "1",
        "tripDate": "2017-08-01 15:45:55",
        "startTime": "15:45:55",
        "endTime": "14:48:55",
        "shiftId": "1",
        "tripStatus": "0",
        "id": "2",
        "empId": "G2E200",
        "callStartTime": "",
        "callEndTime": "",
        "cabReachingTime": "",
        "pickupTime": "",
        "dropTime": "",
        "dropStatus": "0",
        "otp": "",
        "pickupotpStatus": "0",
        "empPresentStatus": "0",
        "latitdute": "12.9630167",
        "longitude": "77.6268656"
    }
]
}
```

My expected answer:

In AJAX response response when I am getting `"status": "success",`, that time only I want to display my map, how can I do this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to initialize map at the beginning, remove callback function on the URL.

```
 &callback=initMap
```

Otherwise:

> When the API is ready, it will call the function specified using the
>   callback parameter.

After, check `status` whether success or not according to JSON, and to initialize the map by button, then, invoke `initMap` function :

```
success: function(data) {
    var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    if(res.status == "success") 
    {
      initMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mr@Gurkan Yesilyurt, i tried your way it is working,in my js now latitude and longitude are static,but i want to make it dynamic, like my json response i have 2 results(lat & lng), in this lat & lng only i want display map, how can do this?

Comment: Mr @ Gurkan, please see here      var waypts = [];
  waypts.push({
    location: {
      lat: 12.9583665,
      lng: 77.6635659
    }, // HAL
    stopover: true
  }, {
    location: {
      lat: 12.9630167,
      lng: 77.6268656
    },
    stopover: true
  }); 

Here i am giving static lat & lng values instead  this i want to give my dynamic lat & lng (coming from JSON response)

Comment: @subikshanM you can get any data which you want and pass it functions. for example; to get first latitdute, type res.data[0].latitdute because data is array. And please up this answer and mark as accepted, maybe better open new question about this.